# Modify programmatically connection string in the app.config before start service

Tags: c#, connection, app-config

I have a problem with programmatically change connection string in the app.config file.
In overriden OnStart method I want to change app.config file(only connection string)
At this moment I have this:

```
 private static void ChangeConnectionString(string newDatasource)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
            var query = from p in doc.Descendants("connectionStrings").Descendants()
                         select p;
            foreach (var child in query)
            {
                foreach (var atr in child.Attributes())
                {
                    if (atr.Name.LocalName == "name" && atr.Value == "UniversityEntities" &&
                        atr.NextAttribute != null && atr.NextAttribute.Name == "connectionString")
                    {
                        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = newDatasource;
                        connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "UniversityDB";
                        connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

                        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(atr.NextAttribute.Value);
                        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
                        atr.NextAttribute.Value = entityBuilder.ToString();

                    }
                }

            }
            doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionString");
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to go for such hacky solution instead of editing the file manually and then start the service?

Comment: I want to allow administrator(user) change connection to database via WinForms application.

Comment: My approach(see above) doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried using Google, or MSDN directly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create a UI to modify the config you can do that. but it wouldn't happen within  the application itself.

1st you have the service/app that will be affected.
2nd you have another app that will change the file.

when the admin clicks "change connection string" from the 2nd app, the 2nd app will stop the 1st service/app. change the connection string. start the 1st service/app.

so from the perspective of the 1st app it won't have to think about hacking together a connection string.

*--------------------------------------*

an alternative is to remove the connection string for the config file altogether and simply make the connection string a required parameter when the application starts. so if it's a server it might look like this

net start [name of service] "the connection string..."

from the 2nd UI you could just overwrite a bat/ps script that starts/stops the service. this way you don't have to hack through the xml of the app.config file.

*--------------------------------------*

one last comment. remove the try/catch, it's completely useless and you need to know if there are problems when changing the file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the connection string why not you add multiple Connection string in your app.config file and use them in your code according to your need.

Here is an Example:

```
//In app.config there are two connection string entry.
<connectionStrings>
<add name="BASE_ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;USER ID=;Password="
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="" connectionString="server=;User Id=;database=;password="
  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

You can switch between these two entries in run time by:

```
string strTesaConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TESA_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string strBaseConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BASE_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
if(1)
{
  using (MySqlConnection DBConnection = new MySqlConnection(strTesaConnectionString))
   { ... }
}
if(2)
{
  using (MySqlConnection DBConnection = new MySqlConnection(strBaseConnectionString ))
   { ... }
}
```